# Word VSTO add-in development: How to find the color of a text in a Range in RGB format?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I'm developing an add-in for MS Word using C#. I need to find the color of the text within a Range object in RGB format.

- I tried using **Range.Font.Color**, which is supposed to give the RGB value. But I'm getting negative and out-of-range values from it.
- **Range.Font.TextColor** gives me a NotImplemented exception.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Please help me.

Comment: Would you be willing to save the Range off as XML and then query the w:color , and convert its hex value to RGB? If a Range.

Comment: Yeah, I also had that as an option. Can you please provide me with some link where I can read about working with Word Open XML?

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497448.aspx

Comment: I will try to dig up some good working sample code as well. I did ensure that you can reliably get the OpenXML of JUST a specific Selection.Range, so this should work with just a Range object as well. the OOXML shows the w:color in hex, so you would just need to translate the hex to RGB (which is straightforward as well).

Comment: This won't be 100% reliable since a single Range.WordOpenXML call can return an XML doc consisting of more than one w:color. Back to the drawing board using Interop? Unless you think you won't have more than one color in a single Range,  this is unreliable

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little test method that can put html style tags for the font color into the document (I needed to do that for bold and italic and just wanted to see if I could get the color) If you fiddle with it you might be able to get what you need it's c# vsto for Word

```
private void TEST()
{
        Range currentWord = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Words.First;
        object collapseStartObj = WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;
        object oText = "";
        object oMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object oFindStop = WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
        object oCountOne = 1;
        object oWordUnit = WdUnits.wdWord;
        int count = 0;
        while (currentWord != null)
        {
            count++;
            currentWord.Find.Font.Bold = currentWord.Font.Bold;
            currentWord.Find.Font.Italic = currentWord.Font.Italic;
            currentWord.Find.Font.ColorIndex = currentWord.Font.ColorIndex;
            string text = currentWord.Font.ColorIndex.ToString();
            string thatColor = Regex.Replace(text, @"\d", ""); //remove any digits
            string simpleColor = Regex.Replace(thatColor, "wd", "");//remove the wd
            //MessageBox.Show(simpleColor); //for testing

            currentWord.Find.Forward = true;
            currentWord.Find.Format = true;
            currentWord.Collapse(ref collapseStartObj);
            currentWord.Find.Execute(ref oText, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oFindStop, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss, ref oMiss);
            if (simpleColor != "NoHighlight")
            {
                try
                {
                    string theText = currentWord.Duplicate.Text;
                    string thatText = Regex.Replace(theText, "\r", "");//get rid of carriage return

                    currentWord.Find.Execute(FindText: thatText, Format: true, ReplaceWith: "<font style = \"color:" + simpleColor + "\">^&</font>", MatchWildcards: true, Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);

                }
                catch { }
            }
        currentWord = currentWord.Next(ref oWordUnit, ref oCountOne);
        }    
 }
```

Comment: This code shows me only limited colors like Red, Gray, etc. Also, things like No Highlight are being shown. I need the color to in RGB format.

Answer (score -1):

Convert a Range.Font.Color to a System.Drawing.Color using Don Rotman's extension method for  [Converting Word 2007’s WdColor to .NET Color Class](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorr/archive/2008/11/16/converting-word-2007-s-wdcolor-to-net-color-class.aspx)

```
 MSWord.WdColor color = app.Selection.Range.Font.Color;
 Color myColor = color.ToColor(); //ToColor is the extension method described in link
```

Now, even when the Range.Font.Color does not return an actual enumeration value like WdOrange but instead returns something like: -654245889 , it will be converted to System.Drawing.Color object which contains all of the RGB data.

Works for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: The link is not working - and thus the extension method is unavailable, rendering this answer dead. Too bad, I could have really used it now.